# Scrapy returns only first item of each letter in alphabetical list

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm totally new to stackoverflow and to python and scrapy. I need to scrape a few glossaries, so far most went fine but I'm posting the script for the one i'm struggling with below. I only get the first entry for each letter and I can't figure out why... any help greatly appreciated! thanks! nic

here's the code:

```
    import scrapy


class GlossarySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'glossary'
    allowed_domains = ['www.edmunds.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.edmunds.com/glossary/']

    def parse(self, response):
        results = response.xpath ("//div[@class='content']/dl")
        for result in results:
            title = result.xpath(".//dt/text()").get()
            text = result.xpath(".//dd/text()").get()
            yield{
                'title': title,
                'text': text
            }
```

Comment: How do you call the `parse()` function? A generator is not easy to understand for python  beginners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getall()` method to return a list with all results.

By the way after getting list of results, you need to modify your code a bit to actually map between name and it's definition.

After getting the list, you can simply iterate over it then write to csv file. Below is an **example**:

```
     with open('test.csv', 'a') as f:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
        for result in results:
            title = result.xpath(".//dt/text()").getall()
            text = result.xpath(".//dd/text()").getall()
            for i in range(len(title)):
                csv_writer.writerow([title[i], text[i]])
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. I did that, but then the .csv has all titles in a single field and all text in another. I'd like to get the output to look like this: {'title': 'OEM', 'text': 'Original equipment manufacturer, i.e., the manufacturer of a vehicle.'}, {'title': 'Parallel hybrid', 'text': 'A vehicle that is powered by an electric motor and an internal combustion engine that are inline. This type of hybrid can be driven on either full electric mode, gasoline engine mode, or combined. This is the most common type of hybrid vehicle currently used today.'}, etc.

Comment: A simple solution is you can iterate over the list:         `for i in range(len(title)):
            print('{}: {}'.format(title[i], text[i]))`

Comment: sorry for the stupid question, but where would I add this into the code?

Comment: You can check this for reference:         `for result in results:
            title = result.xpath(".//dt/text()").getall()
            text = result.xpath(".//dd/text()").getall()

            with open('test.csv', 'a') as f:
                csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
                for i in range(len(title)):
                    csv_writer.writerow([title[i], text[i]])`

Comment: This is the  simplest solution, not consider about performance. I have updated it in the answer above, if you found it's helpful please Up vote, Thanks.